# Trouble Installing PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, plugins, cordova

I'm trying to install a PhoneGap plugin located here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/MessageBox.  However, I am unable to get it working.

Here are the steps I have tried:

1. Make sure your PhoneGap Xcode project has been updated for the iOS 4
   SDK
2. Drag and drop the MessageBox folder from Finder to your Plugins
   folder in XCode, using "Create groups for any added folders"
3. Add the .js files to your www folder on disk, and add reference(s)
   to    the .js files as tags in your html file(s)
4. Add new entry with key MessageBox and value MessageBox to Plugins in
   PhoneGap.plist

On my HTML page, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var messageBox = window.plugins.messageBox;
messageBox.alert('Title', 'Message', function(button) { console.warn('alert', [this, arguments]); });
</script>
```

(note that the required .js file is included earlier in the page)

When I run the project, though, I unfortunately do not see any message boxes.  Just my HTML page.
I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT: Maybe there is an error in that Javascript code I've shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the deviceready to be called in phonegap? if not then you should do that in order that the plugins and all necessary pieces have time to initialize before you call the message box

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I have verified that the call is made after `onDeviceReady()`

Comment: mmm have you tried putting a breakpoint in the objective c code for the plugin. This will tell you if it is being called or not from the javascript and help narrow down the options. However try prompt and see if that works since the alert calls a different plugin based on the javascript it is calling the navigator.notification method and not the messagebox method since there is only prompt in it

Comment: Sorry -- what do you mean try prompt?  I tried putting a breakpoint in MessageBox.m, and nothing happened, so I assume that means the Objective-C isn't even getting called?

Comment: If you look inside the MessageBox.m file there is only the prompt function that is callable the other alert and other pieces were being called from somewhere else. Try using the prompt function it was in the javascript and that should tell you whether it is being called or not

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint here: `// Create UIAlertView popup
 UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
              message:message
             delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle 
             otherButtonTitles:okButtonTitle, nil];`  Unfortunately, though, the breakpoint is not activated.  Does this mean I haven't correctly linked the Objective-C file somehow?