# Incorrectly Linking Javascript File?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plugins, cordova

I'm working on installing a PhoneGap plugin on an iPhone.  The page for the plugin I am attempting to install can be seen here:  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/MessageBox.

I believe I have narrowed down my problem to incorrectly working with the JavaScript file.  I am including it on my HTML page like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="MessageBox.js"></script>
```

The rest of my HTML page is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("test1");
var messageBox = window.plugins.messageBox;
alert("test2");
messageBox.alert('Title', 'Message', function(button) { console.warn('alert', [this, arguments]); });
</script>
```

I see an alert saying **test1**, but not the second alert.  This makes me think that the error is on the line:

```
var messageBox = window.plugins.messageBox;
```

However, I'm not quite sure what I should be doing differently.  From what I can tell, I've done all the necessary steps as described on the plugin's documentation page, seen here: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/MessageBox/README.md

(As expected, I also do not see the output of the messageBox.alert... line when viewing this through the iOS simulator.)

I would appreciate any help with this issue, thanks!

NOTE: my initial thread regarding this topic can be seen here: [Trouble Installing PhoneGap Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182888/trouble-installing-phonegap-plugin)

EDIT: I should also add that I have the exact same problem when trying to install a different (but similar) plugin, known as "Prompt"

EDIT2: Here's my index.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MessageBox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onBodyLoad()
    {       
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }


    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
        window.location.href="otherpage.html";
    } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to create your MessageBox, PhoneGap is not ready yet.

You just need to wait for PhoneGap to be ready before you execute your code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.location="otherpage.html";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, on otherpage.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="MessageBox.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log("onLoad");
            var messageBox = window.plugins.messageBox;
            messageBox.alert('Title', 'Message', function(button) { console.warn('alert', [this, arguments]); });
        }  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested it on PhoneGap 1.4.1

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This does indeed work when I place this code on the index.html file created by PhoneGap.  Currently, in my index file, I use Javascript to redirect to another page, i.e. I have this in my index.html code: `window.location.href="otherpage.html"`  Is there a way I can also use this MessageBox plugin on that page?  When I try the code you posted on that page (otherpage.html), it seeems that onDeviceReady() isn't called.  Perhaps it can't be called a second time?  Is there some workaround for that?  Thanks again for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  For some reason though, when I click the alert button, the MessageBox does not show.  Would there be a way to fix this, or perhaps a way to display it without showing the button at all?  (By having it show right when the page is loaded, for example?)  Thanks again!

Comment: what version of Phonegap are you using again ?

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap version 1.3.0.

Comment: Strange.  I have tried your new code, but I still don't see the MessageBox.  In fact, `onDeviceReady()` doesn't even get called at all.  I checked here: http://phonegap.com/2012/01/31/phonegap-1-4-released/  and I can't seem to think that any of those changes would play a role here.  Would it be worth trying anyway?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it turns out. Can't hurt to upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running into the same problem.  I have noticed, though, that on otherpage.html, `onLoad()` is called whereas `onDeviceReady()` is not.

Comment: I edited my answer with the whole HTML pages. Also be sure you added you plugin to the Plugins section in PhoneGap.plist..

Comment: My otherpage.html is identical to yours, but my index.html is slightly different.  I've added it to my original post -- does that look OK?

Comment: Working fine on my project. Be sure you added the plugin as explained on the MessageBox GitHub readme

Comment: Try to add console.log("") everywhere and see which ones fire and which ones don't to see where it doesn't work

Comment: According to the console.log() output, the only function called, of the four, is `onDeviceReady()` within the index.html file.  Neither of the two are called from otherpage.html.

Comment: Are you sure you otherPage.html is next to index.html and is called ?

Comment: Yes, when I try with a regular javascript: `alert("test");`, that does indeed show up.

Comment: How about you send me your zipped project at titouan.vanbelle at orange fr. I'll see whats wrong.

Comment: It seems for some reason, even though I updated, it still wasn't running the proper PhoneGap version.  I fixed this and now it does seem to work.  Thank you for the help!